# Getting org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: Strict stubbing argument mismatch while using restTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, resttemplate

**I call external API by using RestTemplate's exchange() in my application. And currently, I am writing junit and mockito test case for restTemplate call but I am getting stubbing argument mismatch exception.**

**Here is my code**

```
@Service
public class ApiService {

  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  
  @Value("{url}")
  private String url;
  
  public TrackResponse getTpiValue(TrackRequest trackRequest){
  
    TrackResponse trackResponse = null;
    
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    
    HttpEntity<TrackRequest> entity = new HttpEntity<TrackRequest>(trackRequest, headers);
    
    ResponseEntity<TrackResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.Post, entity, TrackResponse.class);
    
    if(response.getStatusCode == HttpStatus.ok){
       trackResponse = response.getBody();
    }
  return trackResponse;
  }

}
```

**Here is my test case**

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith(MocikotExtension.class)
public class ApiServiceTest {

  @Mock
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  
  @InjectMocks
  private ApiService apiService;
    
  public void getTpiValueTest(){
  
    TrackRequest trackRequest = new TrackRequest();
    trackRequest.setId("UTHL10");
    
    TrackResponse trackResponse = new TrackResponse();
    trackResponse.setTrackId("QWEDRTHFDS");
    
    ResponseEntity<TrackResponse> response = new ResponseEntity<>(trackResponse, HttpStatus.ok);
    
    when(restTemplate.exchange(eq(null), eq(HttpMethod.Post), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(TrackResponse.class))).thenReturn(response);
    
    TrackResponse finalResponse = apiService.getTpiValue(trackRequest);
    
    assetEquals(response.getbody(), finalResponse.getTrackId());
  }

}
```

**But when I run test cases then I am getting below error**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'exchange' method:
    restTemplate.exchange(
    null,
    POST,
    <com.application.track.TrackRequest@3c486eb1,[]>,
    class com.application.track.TrackResponse
);
    -> at com.application.track.ApiService.getTpiValue(ApiService.java:18)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. restTemplate.exchange(
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
);
-> at com.application.track.ApiServiceTest.getTpiValueTest(ApiServiceTest.java:21)
```

I also tried with lenient() but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual method call is :

```java
exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)
```

But now as you stub the first parameter as `NULL` , compiler does not knows its type. So it thinks you are stubbing the methods that has 4 parameters which is :

```
exchange(URI url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, Class<T> responseType)
```

So the actual method call is never be stubbed and it should return NULL or `UnnecessaryStubbingException` to me. No ideas why you get `PotentialStubbingProblem` though...

Anyway try to change to the following should let you stub the actual method that `ApiService` will call correctly :

```java
 when(restTemplate.exchange((String)eq(null), eq(HttpMethod.Post), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(TrackResponse.class))).thenReturn(response);
```

or better yet :

```java
 when(restTemplate.exchange((String)isNull(), eq(HttpMethod.Post), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(TrackResponse.class))).thenReturn(response);
```

Comment: "No ideas why you get `PotentialStubbingProblem`": Mockito will do this if using strict stubs, as it seems the asker is.

Comment: not really. strict stubs will also raise `UnnecessaryStubbingException`

Comment: @KenChan I also tried with anyString() instead of eq(null) but got same error.

Comment: @KenChan I tried (String)eq(null) and it works. Thanks a lot. you saved my time.

Comment: @Rahul `anyString()` does _not_ match null, only non-null strings